# Flushing heroku's request queue

Tags: performance, testing, heroku

I'm tuning my application and running stress tests.

When throwing enough requests at my app, Heroku starts queueing them, but they are consumed so slowly that I have to wait 2-3 minutes for the queues to drain.

While waiting for the queues to drain, the app is practically down and it is impossible to run the next test.

Is there a way to manually flush Heroku's request queue?